# Is a CSS Reset recommended, even though all but the container element are positioned absolute?

Tags: css, browser, css-reset

I am just wondering if it's necessary to include a CSS reset, even though I would be positioning all elements but the container element absolute? Note, this is for banner ad builds only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning everything is bad practice...

Considering using a grid css framework if you want easy positioning and layout.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned this is for banner design not sites. Thanks

Comment: Then yes you should be using CSS reset if you want to expect the same rendering on all browsers including legacy. Modern browsers are all following the same display rules though, so CSS resets are becoming less relevant.

Comment: Ok thanks, but what I wanted to understand is if absolutely positioned elements would even be effected by any added padding or margin that a browser would add for example. When you say modern browsers what versions would require that reset then? Is there a chart of some sort? Thanks